# Does anyone know how long the peer review process usually takes in the human-computer interaction journal

Tags: publications, journals, journal-workflow

Does anyone know how long the peer review process usually takes in the human-computer interaction journal (http://www.tandfonline.com/toc/hhci20/current)?
I couldn't find any information in their website

Answer (score 3):

I looked at your link... for the first article I clicked on we see:

> Received 28 Apr 2015, Accepted 16 Aug 2016, Accepted author version posted online: 01 Sep 2016

So it looks like 16 months in that case.